# How to show user created node in user's profile page in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I need to show user created page content on own profile page.In my site user will create a node content then I need to show user created node content in user profile page.
For this I am creating a views.. But I am not getting how to show particular user created node.. In my case all nodes are showing.

Answer (score 1):

Entity View Attachment will do the job for you. [Here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-views-attach/) is a tutorial about that.

if you don't want to use a new module , views can handle it by its own , first of all create a page of that view and then use these settings :

[image]

then what you need is a contextual filter . these settings will work for you:

[image]

and then :

[image]

now save settings . go to a user profile page and you will see a new tab which shows users contents .